# How to change the color of the first column of a ngx-datatable

Tags: css, angular

I have a [ngx-datatable](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/) like this:

```
<ngx-datatable
    class="material striped"
    [scrollbarV]="false"
    [scrollbarH]="true"
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="col"
    [rowHeight]="35"
    [headerHeight]="40"
  >
  </ngx-datatable>
```

How I change the color of the first column?